# Incorrect description of Archaeologist hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

The description of the [Archaeologist hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/archaeologist) says:

> earn the revival badge for an answer created during Winter Bash

This *seems* to mean, "during Winter Bash, post an answer and earn the Revival badge for it".
But I got the hat when I earned the Revival badge today for an answer posted a year ago.

Is the description incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description is correct, but I screwed up the awarding of the hats. This is fixed now, but we've decided to not revoke the hats that were erroneously awarded. So whoever earned a Revival badge while this was broken got lucky; after the fix, only users matching the description are awarded new Archaeologists.

Answer (score 2):

I agree the description is incorrect.

I think the right interpretation is :

> In order to earn the revival badge, you must post an answer. The answer must meet the badge criteria during the winterbash duration. I suppose you had your second upvote within the Winterbash.

But still. Only the developers know the right interpretation.

Comment: Yet the OP earned the badge for a post **not** created during the Winter bash. **That is the issue the OP is pointing out**; the description appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Misread I will update.

Comment: If that's the case, I think the description should just say "earn the revival badge". Either that, or the developer who coded the hat forgot to check the date of the answer.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the list of assigned badges on various site. Each revival badge earned during the bash seems to be associated with a Archaeologist hat user. So I assume you are right.

I propose to change the description to:

> earn the revival badge during Winter Bash for one of your answers (regardless of the answer post date).

Either that, or the script that is giving out hats is broken (which is probable, I heard rumors that this year they were using trained monkeys :P)

Edit:
Actually, it may be trained [pandas](https://stackexchange.com/error).

Comment: I'll check with the monkeys and report back.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller hehehe. Actually I admit my error. The original error page was talking about [trained pandas](http://stackexchange.com/error) right ?

Comment: Even if they **were** using pandas, this shouldn't happen. The training regimen obviously needs revamping.